# Why display UIAlertView must be at the end of Thread

Tags: iphone

I'm confused, I want to popup a UIAlertView on the screen. But I find UIAlertView popup just after the whole codes complete or I invoke NSTimer. I want to know the reason about it. 
   Is there anyway let me to control the view visiblility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call any UI methods from a thread other than the main thread. Set up your alert, and use performSelectorOnMainThread to display it.